# Datastax service doesn't start after configuring cassandra.yaml for creating a cluster

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, datastax-enterprise

I am having a problem with configuring my cluster in Cassandra in DSE 5.0. After I change the /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml the service dse (sudo service dse start) doesn't start. I am a beginner so I don't know what to do.

Node1:

```
cluster_name: 'MyCluster'  
num_tokens: 256  
seed_provider:  
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.4.48,10.1.4.49"

listen_address: 10.1.4.48  
broadcast_address: 10.1.4.48  
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0  
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.1.1.48
```

Node2:

```
cluster_name: 'MyCluster'  
num_tokens: 256  
seed_provider:  
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.4.48,10.1.4.49"

listen_address: 10.1.4.49  
broadcast_address: 10.1.4.49  
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0  
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.1.1.49
```

This is what I have changed in each of the two nodes that I want to put in the same cluster. Maybe I need to change another file also?

Comment: Look in the system.log and see what the error is.

Comment: @AlecCollier 
In the system.log the error is that : org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml at ... Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block mapping; expected <block end>, but found BlockMappingStart; in 'reader', line 495, column $ broadcast_address: 10.1.4.48 
     
. The thing that bothers me the most is that i do changes in cassandra.yaml now but the system.log doesnt get updated. its the same as yesterday

Comment: Check the `output.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yaml file format can be very fussy. I usually grab a vanilla `cassandra.yaml` one from an install (same version) and run a `diff`

You may well see some unexpected differences. The most common one is a missing space between the `:` and `<value>` so for example

`listen_address:192.168.56.20`

instead of

`listen_address: 192.168.56.20`